# mockito -using one of the values from list of values to compare in matcher

Tags: junit, mockito, matcher

My method interface is

```
Boolean isAuthenticated(String User)
```

I want to compare from list of values if any of the users are passed in the function from the list, then it should return true.

```
when(authService.isAuthenticated(or(eq("amol84"),eq("arpan"),eq("juhi")))).thenReturn(true);
```

I am using additional argument matcher 'or' but above code is not working. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`or` does not have a three-argument overload. ([See docs.](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/AdditionalMatchers.html#or(T,%20T))) If your code compiles, you may be importing a different `or` method than `org.mockito.AdditionalMatchers.or`.

`or(or(eq("amol84"),eq("arpan")),eq("juhi"))` should work.

You might also try the [`oneOf` Hamcrest matcher](https://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.2/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#oneOf-T...-) (previously [`isOneOf`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#isOneOf(T...))), accessed through the [`argThat` Mockito matcher](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/hamcrest/MockitoHamcrest.html#argThat(org.hamcrest.Matcher)):

```
when(authService.isAuthenticated(
         argThat(is(oneOf("amol84", "arpan", "juhi")))))
    .thenReturn(true);
```

Comment: since `argThat(isOneOf("amol84", "arpan")` is deprecated by now use `argThat(is(oneOf("amol84", "arpan"))`

Comment: @GedankenNebel Thanks for spotting this! I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could define separate answers:

```
when(authService.isAuthenticated(eq("amol84"))).thenReturn(true);
when(authService.isAuthenticated(eq("arpan"))).thenReturn(true);
when(authService.isAuthenticated(eq("juhi"))).thenReturn(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not interested in pulling in a library, you can iterate over all of the values you want to add to the mock:

```
// some collection of values
List<String> values = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");

// iterate the values
for (String value : values) {
  // mock each value individually
  when(authService.isAuthenticated(eq(value))).thenReturn(true)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For me this works:

```
public class MockitoTest {

    Mocked mocked = Mockito.mock(Mocked.class);

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Mockito.when(mocked.doit(AdditionalMatchers.or(eq("1"), eq("2")))).thenReturn(true);

        Assert.assertTrue(mocked.doit("1"));
        Assert.assertTrue(mocked.doit("2"));
        Assert.assertFalse(mocked.doit("3"));
    }
}

interface Mocked {
    boolean doit(String a);
}
```

Check if you're setting up mockito correctly, or if you're using the same Matchers as I do.